# open_basedir restriction warnings in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this problem in my backup database in wordpress in `wp-admin`. How should I fix it?

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(E:\Inetpub\vhosts\churrascaria-gaucho.com\httpdocs/.maintenance)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (E:/Inetpub/vhosts/churrascaria-gaucho.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in
>   E:\Inetpub\vhosts\churrascaria-gaucho.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\load.php
>   on line 146
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   E:\Inetpub\vhosts\churrascaria-gaucho.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\load.php:146)
>   in
>   E:\Inetpub\vhosts\churrascaria-gaucho.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\pluggable.php
>   on line 881

Answer (score 0):

The open_basedir function defines the locations or paths from which PHP is allowed to access files using functions like fopen() and gzopen(). If a file is outside of the paths defined by open_basdir, PHP will refuse to open it. That's why you are receiving this warning. you can turned off open basedir restrictions in the Apache configuration file, httpd.conf, with the following line: `php_admin_value open_basedir none`.